# Hiram: 120 talents of gold for what?

Tags: 1-kings

1 Kings 9, 11-14 says:

> King Solomon gave twenty towns in Galilee to Hiram king of Tyre, because Hiram had supplied him with all the cedar and juniper and gold he wanted. But when Hiram went from Tyre to see the towns that Solomon had given him, he was not pleased with them. “What kind of towns are these you have given me, my brother?” he asked. And he called them the Land of Kabul, a name they have to this day. Now Hiram had sent to the king 120 talents of gold.

What is the meaning of the last phrase (verse 14)? If Hiram was not pleased with the towns, then why did he sent 120 more talents of gold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the other-way around.  Hiram had supplied Solomon with:

- expensive wood, cedar and juniper
- gold
- other materials
- skilled craftsmen to do the building of the temple

In payment, Solomon gave Hiram 20 towns which Hiram regarded as poor payment.  That is the 120 talents of gold is the amount of the "gold" listed among the building materials listed in 1 Kings 9:11.

Comment: Now it's clear, thanks! Some Italian translations (like [Nuova Diodati](https://www.laparola.net/testo.php?riferimento=1Re%209,14&versioni[]=Nuova%20Diodati), [Ricciotti](https://www.laparola.net/testo.php?riferimento=1Re%209,14&versioni[]=Ricciotti), [Martini](https://www.laparola.net/testo.php?riferimento=1Re%209,14&versioni[]=Martini)) lead me to read like: "Then Hiram had sent to the king 120 talents of gold", "Moreover, Hiram had sent to the king 120 talents of gold". Those small adverbs confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Verse 14 is a partial explanation of why Hiram was discontented. As a general rule in the ANE, people didn't generally buy and sell as we think of it today. Instead, one person would offer the other a "gift" and in turn would be "gifted" something of equal value. Marcel Mauss' book The Gift is probably the best book out there to briefly explain this system.

Anyways, 1 kings 9:11-14 commemorates such an exchange in which Hiram felt he was drastically shorted, and verse 14 is the explanation of why he felt shorted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).